# Crafting HTML elements from dynamic PHP data

Tags: php, html, jquery, twitter

I apologise for the potentially nebulous title, but I hope that the question will clarify why I've called it that.

I've gotten into webdev from UI design/dev so I'm finding the programming and design aspects fairly easy to handle. However, I'm not used to using three/four different languages with a fair amount of overlap to do a single thing.

In this case, I've written up a PHP script to pull the latest $n tweets from $x user. Currently I'm loading the Twitter PHP via jQuery, crafting the HTML for the tweet in PHP, echoing in the PHP, this is then plopped into a timeline element in the jQuery's callback function.

This way of doing it seems a bit hacky? I was just hoping someone would be able to point me towards another way, or at least waylay my concerns regarding this method.

Here's some Code:

HTML:

```
<section id="twitterContainer">
    <section id="glitchTimeline" class="timeline">
        <!--Twitter articles go here-->
    </section>  
</section>
```

Javascript:

```
function getTweets(n,user)
{
    //This is run when the page is loaded
    //Will be changing this to an ajax call later, aware that it's a bit silly as is.
    $('<article class="twitterPost">').load("http://xxxxxxxxx.com/php/index.php?user="+user+"&count="+n, function(data){
        $(this).appendTo("#glitchTimeline");
    });
}
```

PHP:
(This is called once the twitter API stuff has come back)

```
function craftTweet($jsonStr)
{
    $json = json_decode($jsonStr);
    for($i = 0; $i<count($json); $i++)
    {
        echo '<img class="twitterAvatar" src=' . $json[$i]->user->profile_image_url .' alt=' . $json[$i]->user->screen_name .' width="48">';
        echo '<div class="tweetText">';
        echo '      <b>' . $json[$i]->user->screen_name .'</b><span>@' . $json[$i]->user->screen_name . '</span><span> </span>';
        echo '      <p>' . $json[$i]->text . '</p>';
        echo '      <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id=' . $json[$i]->id . '"><img class="twitterIconFav" src="img/utils/transBackground.png"></a>';
        echo '      <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=' . $json[$i]->id . '"><img class="twitterIconRetweet" src="img/utils/transBackground.png"></a>';
        echo '      <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=' . $json[$i]->id . '" target="_blank"><img class="twitterIconReply" src="img/utils/transBackground.png"></a>';
        echo '      <div class="clearfix"> </div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show some code or a fiddle?

Comment: Sure. Will have to be none working as I'll need to take out my OAuth stuff

Comment: This seems pretty normal to me, since you can't have the twitter API key & OAuth in JS.